# Python - Check Multiple String Value For Chars

Tags: python, while-loop

I know this is a double up of the other questions I have asked today. But this is the most current, and I have put in for the others to be deleted.

This is my code currently:

> def Main():
>
> chars = set('0123456789')
>
> while True:
>
> ```
>    Class_A_Input = raw_input('Enter Class A tickets sold: ')
>
>    Class_B_Input = raw_input('Enter Class B tickets sold: ')
>
>    Class_C_Input = raw_input('Enter Class C tickets sold: ')
>
>    if any((c in chars) for c in Class_A_Input):
>
>        break
>
>    else:
>
>        print 'Wrong'
> ```

I have been able to use the 'if any((c in chars) for c in Class_A_Input)' when there is only 1 user input at a time.

Is there a way to check with this kind of method, all 3 user inputs, and to break the loop if they are fine, otherwise to display 'Wrong' and start the loop over again for the user to input.

Thanks for your patience and help.

Comment: What was wrong with the last two questions? Why didn't you just edit them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to check if the input of users has digit number, if that is right,
then you can use

```
import re

def hasDigit(s):
    return not not re.search("\d", s)

def Main():
    while True:
        Class_A_Input = raw_input('Enter Class A tickets sold: ')
        Class_B_Input = raw_input('Enter Class B tickets sold: ')
        Class_C_Input = raw_input('Enter Class C tickets sold: ')

        if all([hasDigit(Input) for Input in [Class_A_Input, Class_B_Input, Class_C_Input]]):
            break
        else:
            print 'Wrong'
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work.

```
try:
   int(Class_A_Input)
   int(Class_B_Input)
   int(Class_C_Input)
   break
except ValueError:
   print "Wrong"
```

Comment: Also: `somestring.isdigit()` is True iff `somestring` consists entirely of digits.